# NodeJS, Firestore get field

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

I have firestore set up on my nodejs chatbot.
And its successfully copying the Facebook users ID to .doc Name,
and setting there username and other info under there user ID in firestore

How do i go about retrieving this "field"   name
to display back to user.

what i have so far is this

```html
 const givename = db.collection('users').doc(''+ sender_id).get("name");
```

How ever firebase is returning nothing.

Iv looked alot online on how to return a field. but with little luck.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Calling `get()` doesn't *return* the data immediately, since the data is loaded asynchronously. It instead returns a promise, which resolves once the data is loaded. This means that you can use `await` (as in Francisco's answer) or (if `await` is not available) implement the `then()` method:

```
db.collection('users').doc(''+ sender_id).get().then(function(doc) {
  console.log(doc.data().name);
});
```

A common pitfall to be aware of: the `doc.data()` is only available inside the callback,

Comment: Thank your comment.
Still a bit confused.

I get NaN as a response. and firebase log show nothing about the name. which is odd.

What could this mean?

Comment: edit. scratch that. it is. how ever. its now pritining it in the log but not allowing const givename = "code here" 

to work. or is this just not possible?

Comment: I have no idea what that last bit means. But as I said in my answer: the data from `doc.data()` will only be available inside the `then()` callback. See https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93 for more on this way of programming, which is incredibly common in modern JavaScript.

Comment: Ah i see so if i want my code to trigger the name it needs to be within then() so i can use a const for this function to call it when ever i want.. what a bummer. ill fix this issue now and see if i can find a work around :)

Comment: There is no general workaround: learning how async works is by far the best you can do. The closest you can get is using a modern environment and `await` like in Francisco's answer. But if you don't understand asynchronous calls, that too is a leaky abstraction at times.

Comment: How would i use Await instead of .then

i tried .await
or await but dont work. iv installed npm i await and its correctly set up.

Comment: `await` is a keyword introduces in ES2017 (iirc). It's available in Node 8 and later. If you want to try using that, I recommend doing a few searches on "using await in node.js", as they're likely to turn up better explanations than what I can share quickly.

Answer (score 4):

Haven't worked with Firestore yet, but from reading https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

something like below should work (untested):

```
const userRef = db.collection("users").doc("1234")
const userDoc = await userRef.get()
const {name} = userDoc.data()
console.log(name)
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesnt seem to fix the issue.
getting a bunch of userDoc.data is not a function

Comment: userDoc.data is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Another way is:

```
const givename = await db.collection("users").doc("YOUR DOCUMENT NAME").get();

console.log(givename.data().name);
```

Remember to put this code in an `async` function since we are using `await` here